# D3.js TopoJSON plotting points and lines from csv on a map

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm trying to append elements on the map using data from a CSV file, the aim is to achieve the dynamic connections hover as shown in this example http:// bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7608400.

I've been trying to use the example - http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9535021 to plot the points using the same csv, however I am very new to this and failing to understand where the problem originates from.
Below is the d3 call where the map elements are appeneded, which is where I've added the points(circles) to be added as well.

```
d3.json("js/World.json",function(error,geodata) {
  if (error) return console.log(error);

    features.selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(geodata,geodata.objects.collection).features) 
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d",path)
        .on("mouseover",showTooltip)
        .on("mousemove",moveTooltip)
        .on("mouseout",hideTooltip)
        .on("click",clicked);

    d3.csv("csv/us.csv", function(error, data) {
        features.selectAll("circle")
           .data(data)
           .enter()
           .append("circle")
           .attr("cx", function(d) {
                   return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];
           })
           .attr("cy", function(d) {
                   return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0];
           })
           .attr("r", 30)
           .style("fill", "red");
    });

});
```

Rest of the code can be found at: https://jsfiddle.net/pdavr680/

The content of the CSV is the following(a small fragment so not to flood the post):
`name,description,lat,lon
Alabama,Montgomery,32.377716,-86.300568
Alaska,Juneau,58.301598,-134.420212
Arizona,Phoenix,33.448143,-112.096962
Arkansas,Little Rock,34.746613,-92.288986
California,Sacramento,38.576668,-121.493629
Colorado,Denver,39.739227,-104.984856
Connecticut,Hartford,41.764046,-72.682198
Delaware,Dover,39.157307,-75.519722
Hawaii,Honolulu,21.307442,-157.857376
Florida,Tallahassee,30.438118,-84.281296
Georgia,Atlanta,33.749027,-84.388229`

The points are drawn and present in the div, however they're all mashed into one spot x: 0, y: 0, with the error that cx and cy recieved NaN values.
Is the issue in passing the coordinated in .attr ?

PS. In case I wasn't elaborate enough on the question, please let me know so that I could possibly expand on it, prior to getting downvoted.

Comment: You'll need to provide a bit more code here.  In particular, how are you creating your projection?  Are you sure your lat/lon are within that projection?

Comment: Also, at a quick glance, your indexing is backwards on your `cx`/`cy` and try converting your lat/longs to numbers:  `.attr("cx", function(d) { return projection([+d.lon, +d.lat])[0]; }`

Comment: I have added the link to a JSfiddle where I've uploaded all my code, although it doesn't execute there due to missing TopoJSON and CSV files.   
The projection is mercator, however you are correct the projection seems wrong, even though there is an error about NaN values, when i attempt to change them live in Mozilla inspector to the actual coordinates, they barely move.
I've tried using your code, but unfortunately same issue with NaN values.
PS. the points are in the same <div> so there are no issues related to formatting.